# Force xml comment for all members

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For public members I get a warning "missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member ...". That is great, but not enough. I would like to enable this warning for all  (or at least internal and protected) members.

Is there a way to get a warning or information about missing xml comments? Are there any tools at runtime (like Resharper) with that feature?

Comment: I believe protected already raises this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StyleCop (aka MS SourceAnalysis)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/) can do this for you. Here is the [team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/) where you can read more about it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ReSharper use Agent Smith plugin for ReSharper. 
It's open source so feel free to see what goo they have in there.

[Agent Smith HomePage](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/)

[Agent Smith source code on Google Code](http://agentsmithplugin.googlecode.com/)

EDIT: Agent Smith does xml comments validation at code editor runtime(for the lack of the better word)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1425). Its a Microsoft tool that can be integrated into your build and will generate warnings or errors if it's style rules are not followed.

It has a rule: "SA1600: ElementsMustBeDocumented" that would appear to meet your requirements.